$\sum_{{k = 0}}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k} {A}^{k}{B}^{n - k} = 0 $ implies $A=B$?

Let  $A$, $B$ be $n\times n$ real matrices that satisfy
$$\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{k = 0}}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k} {A}^{k}{B}^{n - k} = 0. $$
Prove that  $A = B$.

Is this right? Or what other conditions should be added to ensure $A=B$?
Clearly, the converse is right.

Is $n$ related to the size of $A$ and $B$?

Take $B=0$, then does $A^n = 0$ imply $A=0$???

I see that you are trying somehow to apply the binomial theorem, i.e.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k} = (b-a)^n
$$
to matrices, in order to deduce $A = B$ from $(A-B)^n = 0$. However, this approach suffers from two problems mainly, described below.
Non-commutativity. You are surely aware that matrices don't commute in general. Yet, the binomial theorem is based on the commutatity of the multiplication over real numbers in the end. Indeed, considering a simple example with $n = 2$, one has :
$$
(a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b) = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
$$
However, the simplification $ab + ba = 2ab$ is not true for non-commuting matrices.
Nilpotency. Even if two matrices $A$ and $B$ commute, so that the binomial theorem can be applied and permits to write $(A-B)^n = 0$, this relation doesn't imply $A = B$ in general either, because $A-B = N$ might be a nilpotent matrix, meaning that $\exists n \in \Bbb{N}_{\ge2}$ such that $N^n = 0$. A simple example in two dimensions is given by $A = I_2$ and $B = I_2 - N$, with
$$
N = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, $(A-B)^2 = N^2 = 0$, while $A \neq B$.

You can find $A$ and $B$ with $A\neq B$ such that for a fixed $n$ (or even all $m\ge n$), that sum is indeed $0$ by considering nilpotent block matrices. I'll let you come up with an example.

Why does $(A-B)^{n}=0$ imply $A=B$ when  $A$ and $B$ commute?

Oh nope lol brain fart. Thank you for catching that! You just know that $A-B$ is nilpotent (which $A=B$ can ensure but isn't guaranteed). Fixed!
